# Rounded button on the ListView

Tags: android, listview, button, rounding

I've got layout like this

```
<ListView>
    andorid:layout_width="math_parent"
    android:layout_height="math_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView>
        andorid:layout_width="math_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horisontal" >
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="bla bla"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </ListView>

    .........
</ListView>
```

So my round button is not rounded cause the number of pixels in child layout on height less than in parent main layout. How could i get the round button?
Thanks

Comment: If you want to have `TextView` and `ImageView` in your `ListView` then you should inflate another layout and in that layout you should have `TextView` and `ImageView`. This is not the way to do it.

Comment: What is `round_button`? XML? or image?

Comment: I think you are confused by the concept of `ListView`. What you are trying to achieve is `listview with custom rows`

Comment: Create a custom listview with custom layout for items in list. Just like @Aniruddha said.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I mean button on a circle. It is png image (it is not neccessary i thing, so it can be xml with selector). I don't want to use RelativeLayout with id for all views cause i have many custom child layout, than i should using ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the round button then create an XML file named `round.xml` inside drawable folder.

Then add the following to xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#e5e4e2" />
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
```

Then make this as `background` of Button

```
      <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/myButton"
            android:background="@drawable/round" />
```